# How to click a button and get the result?

Tags: html, css, python-requests, web-crawler

I have a problem while crawling the website https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/journal-of-econometrics/issues. I would have to click a button to let the console to show more information. The website only present the 2024 information, and I want the 2023 one. But I only can extract the button and then I do not know how to do that. Below is my trial code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/journal-of-econometrics/issues"
headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
content = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
span_classes = soup.find_all('span', class_='accordion-title')
# links = soup.find_all('a', class_="anchor js-issue-item-link text-m anchor-default")

for span_class in span_classes:
    span_text = span_class.text
    if '2023' in span_text:
        target_tag = span_class
        
tag_parent = target_tag.parent.parent
```

The `tag_parent` is the button, which can be shown like this when printing:

```
<button aria-controls="266116-accordion-panel-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="true" class="u-display-flex icon-right accordion-panel-title u-padding-s-ver u-text-left" id="266116-accordion-tab-1" role="tab" tabindex="0" type="button"><div><span class="accordion-title">2023 — Volumes 232-237</span></div><svg class="icon icon-navigate-down accordion-icon" focusable="false" height="24" viewbox="0 0 92 128" width="17.25"><path d="m1 51l7-7 38 38 38-38 7 7-45 45z"></path></svg></button>
```

So how can I 'click' this button, and get the information of the 2023 again?

Comment: The Requests library in Python is unable to perform such actions since it doesn't support JavaScript-based interactions like clicking buttons on a webpage. To interact with dynamic content that requires user actions like clicking buttons, you'll need to use tools like Selenium.